# Using Reinforcement learning for minimisation

Tags: data, data-science-model, reinforcement-learning, optimization

I would like to use reinforcement learning for the optimisation of a given function under some contraints.

Take for example the following problems:

`min f(x, y, z) with respect to x, y, z such that x, y and belong to a given domain`

Having some basic knowledge about RL, I assume that the framework could be adapted to handle this problem but I am unable to state it correctly from a RL point of view.

My second question is how efficient RL in these topics? If there any useful resources, I will be thankful.